# Notepad++ how to swap characters in a string

Tags: character, notepad++, swap

I have a computer generated text file. I need to swap positions of certain entries. These entries are always 4 characters long and separated from the rest by semicolons. The 4th character needs to become the first character.

For example:

```
;1234;
```

has to become:

```
;4123;
```

Note: There's a lot of other text separated by semicolons, but only these are exactly 4 characters long. The rest is longer or shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with:

Find what: `;(\d\d\d)(\d);`
Replace with: `;$2$1;`